# In Envoy , how to perform zone aware routing only for request with specific header values?

Tags: envoyproxy

[click here for image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1xG9E.png)

Goal is to allow cross zone routing for request with header header_value=1 and for header_value=2 , only to local cluster as shown in attached image.

How can i achieve this.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

manged to solve this with adding new cluster and route based on header.